# Following links with a second request - Web crawler

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Please bear with me. I am quite new at Python - but having a lot of fun. I am trying to code a web crawler that crawls through results from a travel website. I have managed to extract all the relevant links from the main page. And now I want Python to follow each of the links and gather the pieces of information from each of those pages. But I am stuck. Hope you can give me a hint.

Here is my code:

```
  import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import urllib, collections

  Spider =1

  def trade_spider(max_pages):
  RegionIDArray = {737: "London"}
  for reg in RegionIDArray:
  page = -1
  r = requests.get("https://www.viatorcom.de/London/d" +str(reg) +"&page=" + str(page) , verify = False)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

  g_data = soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "mtm mbn card-title"})
  for item in g_data:
      Deeplink = item.find_all("a")
      for t in set(t.get("href") for t in Deeplink):
          Deeplink_final = t
          print(Deeplink_final) #The output shows all the links that I would like to follow and gather information from.          
  trade_spider(1)
```

Output:

```
    /de/7132/London-attractions/Stonehenge/d737-a113
    /de/7132/London-attractions/Tower-of-London/d737-a93
    /de/7132/London-attractions/London-Eye/d737-a1400
    /de/7132/London-attractions/Thames-River/d737-a1410
```

The output shows all the links that I would like to follow and gather information from.

Next step in my code:

```
   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import urllib, collections

   Spider =1

   def trade_spider(max_pages):
   RegionIDArray = {737: "London"}
   for reg in RegionIDArray:
   page = -1
   r = requests.get("https://www.viatorcom.de/London/d" +str(reg) +"&page=" + str(page) , verify = False)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

   g_data = soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "mtm mbn card-title"})
   for item in g_data:
       Deeplink = item.find_all("a")
       for t in set(t.get("href") for t in Deeplink):
           Deeplink_final = t   
   trade_spider(1)

   def trade_spider2(max_pages):

   r = requests.get("https://www.viatorcom.de" + Deeplink_final,  verify = False)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
   print(soup)

   trade_spider2(9)
```

I would like to append the initally crawled output to my second request. But this doesnt work.Hope you can give me a hint.

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code?

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib, collections

Spider =1

def trade_spider2(Deeplink_final):
   r = requests.get("https://www.viatorcom.de" + Deeplink_final,  verify = False)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
   print(soup)

def trade_spider(max_pages):
   RegionIDArray = {737: "London"}
   for reg in RegionIDArray:
       page = -1
       r = requests.get("https://www.viatorcom.de/London/d" +str(reg) +"&page=" + str(page) , verify = False)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

       g_data = soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "mtm mbn card-title"})
       for item in g_data:
           Deeplink = item.find_all("a")
           for Deeplink_final in set(t.get("href") for t in Deeplink):
               trade_spider2(Deeplink_final)

trade_spider(1)
```

Comment: No explanation?